# Database ERD - Junction Table (one-to-many)

Tags: mysql, database, erd

**OBJECTIVE**

Create a table for Accounts Receivable to input invoice/payment data per customers. Data will be used to determine Account Receivable Aging metrics.

**APPROACH**

1. Create a `customer` table with relevant information
2. Create an `invoice` table with relevant information (including `customerID`)
3. Create a `payments` table that ties `customer` and `invoices` together

**ERD DIAGRAM**

[image]

**NOTES**

- 1 Invoice can have multiple payments (e.g Customer makes partial payments until Invoice is complete)
- Each payment is related back to a single customer (multiple customers will not be paying on behalf of another customer)

**QUESTION**

1. Is my one-to-one for Customer > Payments a proper connection? Customers will be only paying their own invoices, so I believe it's a one-to-one relationship. However, a single Customer can have many payments (for different invoices).
2. If a single customer makes multiple payments on one invoice, I intend to differentiate the payments by 'date_paid' (payments table). Is there a more robust way of distinguishing between 1 customer making multiple payments on 1 invoice?

Answer (score 0):

1. Doesn't look right. We like customers that make more than one payment.  A payment is related to one customer. But a customer can have zero, one or more payments.

That foreign key relationship looks redundant, since a Payment is associated with exactly one Invoice (FK relationship), and an `Invoice` is related to exactly one `Customer` (FK relationship.)

We don't really need to store `Cust_ID` on the `Payment` table. If we do, we give rise to a possible anomaly.  There is nothing that prevents the Invoice from being related to customer 11, and a payment on that Invoice being related to a different customer, 222.

---

2. I wouldn't use Date_Paid to distinguish. We wouldn't want to disallow a customer from making two (or more) payments on the same date. (The customer wants to make a $100 payment, and mistakenly makes a $10 payment. We want to allow them to make another payment of $90.

In my thinking, `Payment` is an actual entity, and not just a relationship between the `Customer` and `Invoice` entities. As such, I would add an entity identifier.  Looking at the existing naming convention, that would be `Payment_ID`. I'd make that the primary key of the table.

Comment: So to clarify, you'd have a `payment_ID` at the PK. Additionally, you recommend making a one-to-many relationship from Customer > Payment table?

Comment: Additionally - I should remove one of the Foreign Keys from the Payment table (since the `cust_ID` and `invoice_id` are already defined in the `Invoice` table, correct?

Comment: The changes I would make to the `Payment` (entity) table: 1) add `Payment_ID` column as primary key and 2) remove the `Cust_ID` column (and the foreign key constraint to `Customer` entity).